Prove $AB^2+DC^2=AC^2+BD^2$
I was reading a book when I came across this statement:
$AB^2+DC^2=AC^2+BD^2$ for$\triangle ABC$ where $\angle ADC = \angle ADB = \angle BAC=90^{\circ}$
$\triangle ABC$" />
I tried using the Pythagoras theorem but couldn't prove it.
My approach:
$AB^2+AC^2=BC^2 \implies AB^2+AC^2=BD^2+DC^2+2\cdot BD\cdot BC $
I thought of breaking down $BD$ and $BC$ by the fact that $ AD^2+DC^2=AC^2$ and the same for $AB$. Is my approach correct, and if yes, how should I proceed?

Isn't $AD^2+DC^2=AC^2$?

Should it be $AB^2 + CD^2 = AC^2 + BD^2$? And should the angle condition be $\angle BAC = \angle ADC = 90^\circ$ rather than $\angle BAD = 90^\circ$?

@MishaLavrov I corrected them

$$AB^2 - BD^2 = AD^2 = AC^2 - CD^2.$$

Or just directly apply Pythagoras for $\Delta ABC$
$$\color{red}{AB^2}+\color{green}{AC^2}=BC^2=(\color{red}{AD^2+DB^2})+(\color{green}{AD^2+DC^2}).$$
